# Does it make sense to allow retrieval of data from OpenGL's context

Tags: oop, opengl

I am trying to abstract some of OpenGLs concepts into an object oriented style, wrapping elements like Buffers, Arrays, Vertices etc. into objects that save their access-id, data-types, buffer-sizes, used indices etc. and provice further simplifications to their usage.

Though right now I mentioned: Does anyone actually want to reaccess this data that was once pushed into the GPU? Are functions like glGetBufferSubData actually ever used other than for Debugging, since the documentation of these functions on the official wiki isn't very elaborate and I have never seen it in any tutorial.

Comment: It can be used ex. for doing general processing on the GPU. But generally you want to minimize downloads from the GPU since it causes pipeline stalls. If you don't need them, don't implement them.

Comment: OpenGL → OOP mapper: "Abandon all hope, ye who enter here." Seriously, it's ridiculously difficult to map a substancial subset of OpenGL into a OOP wrapper that works in all conditions and covers most corner cases. It's virtually impossible to do this with all OpenGL state. I've been there… several times… no fun times.

Comment: Well it is no substantial subset - it's "just" shader programs, vbo/vaos, textures and uniform buffers

Comment: It's exactly that subset that is the hardest to map. The problem is, that textures, VBOs and uniform buffers can be shared across multiple OpenGL contexts. That opens a huge can of worms for OOP wrappers.

Answer (score 3):

GL is the general conecpt that everything can be queried. Reading back stuff that you yourself put should be avoided and is usually more expensive than if you keep a local copy. However, there is also data which is generated by the GPU which you might read back. Examples of this are of course frambeuffer contents, textures you rendered into, or vertex data which you stored via transform feedback into a buffer. So yes, there are real use cases for things like `glGetBufferSubData()` (although I prefer buffer mappings in most situations).

If you need support for such operations is another matter entirely, and one whoch I think is off-topic here and primarily opinion-based. The problem with those abstractions one builds without the intended use case in mind is that one tends to over-abstract things. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program to generate meshes using transform feedback, and needed to read the data in buffers to save the resulting mesh.
The transform feedback generated the data. It wasn't data that I originally pushed there.
So, yes.